# Download image using jquery

Tags: jquery

in my form load i download a image using jquery and when user click on any button then i am showing that image in my div. but only first time image is taking time to visible. if image is downloaded at form load so when i am showing that image through jquery then i think it should not download again and it should be visible very quickly.

### here is my code

```
 var _images = ['/Images/ajax-loader.gif'];
   $.each(_images, function (e) {
       $(new Image()).load(function () {
           //alert($(this).attr('src') + 'has loaded!');
       }).attr('src', this);
   });
```

through the above routine i am downloading image at form load with the help of jquery.

so when i am showing that image when user click on button like below one

```
                   $('#loader').html('<table border="0" style="width:auto"><tr><td valign="middle">Wait...</td><td valign="top"><img height="20px" width="20px" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0" /></td></tr></table>');
```

loader is my div

so the image should not download again rather it should show from the client machine.
so please guide me what is wrong in my code that image is download at form load and inspite of that it is again loading for the first time. please help...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pre-loading `/Images/ajax-loader.gif` and using `/images/ajax-loader.gif` (note I/i). I suspect the browser regards them as different pictures.

Comment: I think that's just a typo.. isn't it ?

Comment: basically i am trying to achieve that i will download image at form load and later i will use those image or show those images in my div without making another request. so please help me with code sample how to achieve it. thanks

Comment: would u please tell me how to achieve what i am trying to do!

Comment: Did you even read my answer? Try changing the capitalization of `/Images/` to `/images/`  or vice versa.

Comment: So u mena to say that if i change /Images/ to /images/ then second time image will not download whenever i refer the same image anywhere in my page? please clarify

Comment: Yes. `Images` is not (always) the same as `images`.

Comment: i just need to know that if i follow ur instruction then image will dowload second time or use from the browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

open up firebug and see what is actually happening.

In my opinion you are making another request to server using jquery since the expiry or cache might not have been set appropriately..

Look into those and include results

also you could do another thing:

Have code something like this :

```
 <div id='loader' style="display:none"><table border="0" style="width:auto"><tr><td valign="middle">Wait...</td><td valign="top"><img height="20px" width="20px" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0" /></td></tr></table></div>
```

and whenever you want to display this just use

```
$('#loader').show();
```

and when you want to hide again

```
$('#loader').hide();
```

Comment: basically i am trying to achieve that i will download image at form load and later i will use those image or show those images in my div without making another request. so please help me with code sample how to achieve it. thanks

Comment: I understood what you are saying.. there are lot of other things than just coding for the caching to occur. You may be making multiple 304 requests.. install firebug and send what you see on the "net" tab